# How to convert a List of one type to a List of another type using Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to use `Stream`s to achieve the following:

I have list of `Input` and `Output` objects having a completely different structure.

With a for loop I can transform a `List<Input>` to a `List<Output>` as follows:

```
for (Input input : listOfInput) {
    Output currentOutPutInstance = new Output();
    currentOutPutInstance.setArg1(input.getArg2());
    currentOutPutInstance.setArg2(input.getArg7());
    listOfOutPuts.add(currentOutPutInstance);
}
```

With streams I tried something like this:

```
private List<Output> getOutPutListFromInputList(List<Input> inPutList) {
    List<Output> outPutList = new ArrayList<Output>();
    outPutList = listOfPoolsInRun.stream.filter(<Somehow converting the input into output>)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

**Note:**  I am not sure which `Stream` method I should be using. I have used `filter` just to show some dummy code.

Comment: why `fillter` ?

Comment: @Mritunjay : it was just an example, i am not sure what i can use here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `map()` to transform a `Stream<Input>` to a `Stream<Output>` :

```
private List<Output> getOutPutListFromInputList(List<Input> inPutList)
{
    return listOfPoolsInRun.stream()
                           .map(input -> {
                                Output out = new Output();
                                out.setArg1(input.getArg2());
                                out.setArg2(input.getArg7());
                                return out;
                            })
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

This could be made shorter if you have the appropriate constructor in the `Output` class :

```
private List<Output> getOutPutListFromInputList(List<Input> inPutList) 
{
    return listOfPoolsInRun.stream()
                           .map(input -> new Output(input.getArg2(),input.getArg7()))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, since an input has to be processed to get an output, it can even be shorter to something like:


return listOfPoolsInRun.stream().map(this::processInputs).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Or, depending on the situation and flavour, if Output knows how to instantiate itself from the input, it could provide a static factory method so you could write `map(Output::fromInput)`

Answer (score 4):

Make this part of your code a method:

```
OutPut createOutput(Input input) {
    OutPut currentOutPutInstance=new Output();
    currentOutPutInstance.setArg1(input.getArg2());
    currentOutPutInstance.setArg2(input.getArg7());
    return currentOutPutInstance;
}
```

Then just `map` over it like that:

```
outPutList = listOfPoolsInRun.stream().map(this::createOutput).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

While having a dedicated method `createOutput` is not necessary I find such code more readable.